# How can I run two commands in CMD or ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

In the [Dockerfile builder](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/), `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` run in one time by using `/bin/sh -c` in back.

Are there any simple solution to run two command inside without extra script

In my case, I want to setup docker in docker in jenkins slave node, so I pass the `docker.sock` into container, and I want to change the permission to be executed by normal user, so it shall be done before `sshd` command.

The normal is like `jenkins`, which will be login into container via `ssh` command.

```
$ docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock larrycai/jenkins-slave
```

In `larrycai/jenkins-slave` Dockerfile, I hope to run

```
CMD chmod o+rw /docker.sock && /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Currently `jenkins` is given sudo permission, see [larrycai/jenkins-slave](https://github.com/larrycai/docker-images/blob/50c2dfddc248dbad776137a6b430052a1348a198/jenkins-slave/Dockerfile)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I run multiple programs in a Docker container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948149/can-i-run-multiple-programs-in-a-docker-container)

Comment: no，first command is not daemon command

Answer (score 0):

**I run docker in docker in jenkins slave:**

*First:* my slave know run docker.

*Second:* I prepare one docker image who knows run docker in docker. See one fragment of dockerfile

```
RUN echo 'deb [trusted=yes] http://myrepo:3142/get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -qqy iptables ca-certificates lxc apt-transport-https lxc-docker
ADD src/wrapdocker /usr/local/bin/wrapdocker
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wrapdocker
VOLUME /var/lib/docker
```

*Third:* The jenkins job running in this slave contain one .sh file with a set of command to run over app code  like:

```
export RAILS_ENV=test
# Bundle install
bundle install

# spec_no_rails
bundle exec rspec spec_no_rails -I spec_no_rails
bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
etc...
```

Fourth: one run shell step job with something like this

```
docker run --privileged -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -v `pwd`:/code myimagewhorundockerindocker /bin/bash -xec 'cd /code && ./myfile.sh'
```

--privileged necessary for run docker in docker

-v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro for synchronize host clock vs container clock

-v `pwd`:/code for share jenkins workspace (app-code) previously cloned from VCS with /code inside container

note: If you have service dependencies you can use fig with similar strategy.