# ssh tunnel to remote dockerized mongo server

Tags: mongodb, ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I have a mongo docker instance  running on a remote server, what is the correct way to access the command line from my local machine?

If i login to the remote host, i can access this by:

$ docker exec -it mongo-dev mongo ccc-mongo

but i am unsure how to do this from my local machine.

I tried this:

```
$ ssh -L 4321:localhost:27017 khine@ccc1 -f -N

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
khine@ccc1's password: 
khine@dhegdheer:~/Sandboxes/$ mongo --port 4321
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:4321/test
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
Wed Sep  9 15:36:44.386 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Wed Sep  9 15:36:44.388 Error: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 127.0.0.1:4321 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
exception: connect failed
```

on my remote machine i have 3 mongo instances running

```
khine@ccc1 /ccc $ docker ps                                
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES

22a32b4f6a1d        redis:2.8                    "/entrypoint.sh redi   7 days ago          Up 7 days           6379/tcp                                   redis-web            
167b022ab793        mongo:2.4                    "/entrypoint.sh mong   7 days ago          Up 7 days           27017/tcp                                  mongo-web            
ab84ea6cb44a        redis:2.8                    "/entrypoint.sh redi   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          6379/tcp                                   redis-www            
04dcc306af04        redis:2.8                    "/entrypoint.sh redi   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          6379/tcp                                   redis-dev            
02c0c18307dc        mongo:2.4                    "/entrypoint.sh mong   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          27017/tcp                                  mongo-www            
61df69ec7edb        mongo:2.4                    "/entrypoint.sh mong   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          27017/tcp                                  mongo-dev
```

running docker inspect, i get this:

```
khine@ccc1 /ccc $ docker inspect 61df69ec7edb
[{
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "Args": [
        "mongod"
    ],
    "Config": {
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "Cmd": [
            "mongod"
        ],
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Cpuset": "",
        "Domainname": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "/entrypoint.sh"
        ],
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "MONGO_VERSION=2.4.14"
        ],
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "27017/tcp": {}
        },
        "Hostname": "61df69ec7edb",
        "Image": "mongo:2.4",

    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/ccc/mongo-data/dev:/data/db"
        ],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "CgroupParent": "",

    "Name": "/mongo-dev",
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "docker0",
        "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.34",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "fe80::42:acff:fe11:22",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 64,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:22",
        "PortMapping": null,
        "Ports": {
            "27017/tcp": null
        }
    },
    "Path": "/entrypoint.sh",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/61df69ec7edb6995f06d797f5b2eed420d0c4daa4cd089c3b9174900d72d0b13/resolv.conf",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "State": {
        "Dead": false,
        "Error": "",
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Pid": 15346,
        "Restarting": false,
        "Running": true,
        "StartedAt": "2015-08-26T06:01:55.361817334Z"
    },
    "Volumes": {
        "/data/db": "/ccc/mongo-data/dev"
    },
    "VolumesRW": {
        "/data/db": true
    }
}
]
```

if i add the IP address for the instance, i get this warning

$ Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 4321
any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Docker runs a "single process" per container and does so "by design". In order to have ssh access you need a "sshd" to be running "as well" as the "mongod" process. Look at something like [supervisord](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/) as advised in the docker documentation itself. That will allow you to run "multiple processes" and effectively have "both" sshd and mongod running on the container.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I run multiple programs in a Docker container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948149/can-i-run-multiple-programs-in-a-docker-container)

Comment: Thanks @BlakesSeven makes sense