# Can I use Docker like this ...?

Tags: docker, linux-mint

My work laptop is running LinuxMint as the base OS, plus Virtualbox to run Windows 7 which is the *actual* work environment, usually plus an additional Virtualbox VM to run a different Windows installation in which I do my client project work (I have one VM per client, to avoid messing up my main OS).

But I'm wondering if it's feasible and beneficent to switch to using Docker for the client project stuff? That is, I'd like to keep LinuxMint (to preserve my sanity), and keep Windows ('cause I have to use some MS products), but then instead of that series of "client VM's" use Docker containers?

I'm not entirely clear on how containers are useful. Can I, for instance, have a container in which I've installed dotNET and MS SQL; and then another container where I've installed an Azure Powershell; and a third container where I've installed Java and Eclipse -- and then decide which of these "sets" of software is available *on the same common base OS* (Windows, with VPN and Outlook and Notepad++)?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948149/can-i-run-multiple-programs-in-a-docker-container) makes me think I'm asking for a solution from the wrong tool?

---

Or should I perhaps attack the root problem from a different angle, and ask the following over at Workplace.SE: *How to work as a consultant without "cluttering up" one's (Windows) OS with more or less temporary installations of all sorts of software necessary for client projects?*

Comment: Probably a better question for a docker forum.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no WindowsOS ready to be run INSIDE a docker container localy, but they are anounced. See [www.docker.com/microsoft](https://www.docker.com/microsoft) and [msdn windowscontainers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/about_overview)

What you can do is run Linux OSs in docker containers within Windows. But in your case you should run the docker engine in your Mint Linux

Answer (score 1):

*Not really an answer, more like several comments -- though it's too long to fit within a comment*

First of all I [would not run Mint](https://lwn.net/Articles/676664/), but that's off the question.

Then, it may probably worth to take a look at [How is Docker different from a normal virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-normal-virtual-machine?rq=1).

Also, [as you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948149/can-i-run-multiple-programs-in-a-docker-container?lq=1), Docker does not aim (at all) to run several programs. Indeed, their policy is Caas: Container as a Service. So basically one program per container. Saying all that, you can probably run `wine` within container and run one application on each container (over `wine`).

Have fun!