# Launch two nodejs app inside Docker container using pm2

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, pm2

I'm trying to launch 2 nodejs app inside a Docker container using PM2, so I made a custom Dockerfile with all the projects config

```
FROM node:argon

RUN npm install pm2 -g --silent

VOLUME ./src/app:/usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN git clone https://github.com/yoonic/atlas.git backend
RUN cd backend && \
    npm i --silent && \
    pm2 start npm --name "backend" -- run dev --no-daemon

RUN git clone https://github.com/yoonic/nicistore.git frontend
RUN cd frontend && \
    npm i --silent && \
    sed -i "s#api.atlas.baseUrl#http://localhost:8000/v1#" config/client/development.js && \
    pm2 start npm --name "frontend" -- run dev --no-daemon
```

I start this container with `docker-compose up` with this config

```
# NodeJS
nodejs:
  build: docker/nodejs
  container_name: nodejs
  ports:
    - 53000:3000
    - 54000:4000
```

When all the container is set up, I get the PM2 process list in my terminal 
then docker-compose start all my containers but I the nodejs one fail instantly

> nodejs exited with code 0

My nodejs app are working inside my container but this one exit instantly...

This the right way to make this work ?
PM2 is maybe not needed ?

How can I make this working ?

**EDIT**

The container exit when I'm not using `--no-daemon` because it think everything is done.
But when I'm using `--no-daemon` the build process is never finished because it show me nodejs app logs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a process file to manage these two applications: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

For example - 
process.yml:

```
apps:
  - script : 'npm'
    args   : 'run dev'
    cwd    : './backend'
    name   : 'backend'
  - script : 'npm'
    args   : 'run dev'
    cwd    : './frontend'
    name   : 'frontend'
```

Then in the Dockerfile:

```
CMD ['pm2-docker', 'process.yml']
```

Documentation about PM2/Docker integration: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, though [you can run several processes in one container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19978556/1211527) usually the best way to go is to use just one process per container. So you would have two services in your `docker-compose.yml` - one for backend and another for frontend.

There are some problems in your `Dockerfile` that need fixing:

1. Use `ADD` or `COPY` instead of `VOLUME` to copy files to container
2. Use `RUN` command just for installing npm packages etc. to prepare an image.
3. Use `COMMAND` or `ENTRYPOINT` to define the command that is run when the container is started.

So, the reason why your container is exiting is that you don't specify your own `COMMAND` and thus the default command from `node:argon` is run. As the default command is to start Node REPL and it exits if the container is not run in interactive mode, your container exits immediately on start-up.

I'm a bit busy now and can't prepare a full example with working code. Can you find your path forward with these tips? :)

Comment: Ok, I will correct my errors, I send you another comment if I still can't make this container to work