# Tmux theme in docker container

Tags: docker, containers, themes, development-environment, tmux

I have used noobs term with my own dotfiles for a long time and have recently started learning `docker`.

I've modified the original shell script (removing all `sudo`) and pointing the dotfiles repo to my own.

I'm using `ubuntu` as my base image with `git`, `curl`, `wget`, `zsh`, `tmux` and `neovim` built from a `Dockerfile` that I attach to.

The container creates a file in `/root` with my script and runs it. Everything seems to work except for the `tmux` nord theme which in my machine was only loaded until I reboot, does any one know how to load the theme in a `docker` container?

Comment: Firstly it is not recommended to use ssh based or terminal sessions in containerized applications. Tmux is for multiple sessions and not recommended to use within containers

Comment: @AvinashReddy why not / [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19978556/1423507)? [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)? No [ssh](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/)?

Comment: terminal sessions in a container is not the problem, if you run a mysql instance you are running a terminal session,it is the same for any other application, nodejs server, rails app, etc. The thing here is that i want to be able to have a development environment containerized for rapid development in case of need. I'm only missing the theme to have the whole setup i need, any idea o that subject?

Comment: @alexzaizar09 got a Dockerfile I could test with?