# How to call java main class from inside docker image using argument parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I have one apps which contains 10 java main class . Each main class has own responsibility.

I want to call each class in docker using class name parameter.

```
My Docker Image like below.
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11
ADD xyzproject/target/abc.jar abc.jar
CMD ["java", "-cp", "abc.jar" ,"Class1"]
```

I want to run multiple class using docker run argument parameter
Please suggest and help me to resolved

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I run multiple programs in a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948149/can-i-run-multiple-programs-in-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply an alternate `CMD` when you launch the container:

```sh
docker run ... xyzproject/abc \
  java -cp abc.jar Class2
```

The Compose `command:` and Kubernetes Pod `args:` similarly replace the `CMD` part.

If the `java` command is too involved, you can write a wrapper script to launch each embedded application:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# run_class3.sh
exec java -cp abc.jar Class3 "$@"
```

```sh
docker run ... xyzproject/abc \
  ./run_class3.sh
```

Comment: I wan to run this command 
docker build -f Dockerfile -t abc .
docker run -it abc

Comment: You can specify the alternate command after the image name `abc` in the second command.

Comment: is this your suggestion -  docker run -it abc java -cp abc.jar  Class1