# Deploying an application with database inside mysql container inside docker

Tags: mysql, .net, wpf, docker, containers

I'm working on a simple application using .net core (wpf) i want to use MySQL container (using docker) for my database and i' am wondering if it is possible to deploy the application and my database is inside MySQL container ?
If yes I'll much appreciate if you could point me on where to start like how to connect my .net core (wpf)  (version : 5.0) application with my MySQL database.

Comment: It's *possible* but it's a bad idea that is going to cause you a lot of extra work and it's the contraindicated method.  You gain nothing and lose so much.   just run mysql and your app in separate containers.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948149/can-i-run-multiple-programs-in-a-docker-container

Comment: yes, that's what i was looking for. thank you ^^